# Why does restcountries API does not work while my Javascript code is correct

Tags: javascript, html, css, api, sass

I'm trying to get data about countries using **Rest Countries API** by using link which is inside  Github repository https://github.com/public-apis/public-apis.
And when I open this API This is what I get.
**{"message":"Page Not Found","_links":{"self":{"href":"/","templated":false}}}**.

And this is my Javascript Code

```
  const getCountryData = function (country) {
  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/${country}`);
  request.send();
  request.addEventListener('load', function () {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  });
};

getCountryData('rwanda');
getCountryData('brazil');
```

What is this happening ???

Comment: When I click on [REST Countries](https://restcountries.com/) in the list of APIs, I land on restcountries.com which says "Page Not Found". However, when I try to call the API from Postman (https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/rwanda), or even directly in the browser, it seems to work, it's only asking me for an API key.

Comment: Do you need a key?

Answer (score 2):

when I try to open the restcountries.eu site it redirects me to this http://countrylayer.com/ site maybe they have changed the domain or if you cannot figure it out then you can check out this site and see if it help you to do what you want to :

https://github.com/samayo/country-json